# AEM - adding a container and varying number of children

Tags: aem, sightly

I have created a component, the new request is to add 3 or 4 of those components within a container. I understand I can just add a column control component and add the children as needed but the request is to go beyond that and add the children as the column control is updated. For example if you change the number of children to 3 the container will automatically add 3 of the original components that were created and so forth.

I have started working extending the Column Control - Sightly component and how I would like to add the children without having to manually add those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard approach for inserting a varying number of components, is to include the Paragraph System Component (**parsys**), and then let the author insert the components he or she needs (can be limited to allow only specific components).

http://wem.help.adobe.com/enterprise/en_US/10-0/wem/wcm/default_components.html#Paragraph%20System%20%28parsys%29

Or is there a specific requirement that you need to be able to specify the number of components beforehand?

Comment: We are grouping components and we are trying to provide a set of groupings that would be easier to manage rather than having to create a Column Control and then the necessary children components to it. We also be able to provide a preset structure rather than letting content authors manage that as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Couldn't you build a wrapper component that consists of your container element and containing a configurable number of your original component (e.g. with cq:includes inside of jstl foreach tags)?

Comment: Yeah, I kind of have come up with that solution, the only problem that I am running into (which is probably another thread) is being able to have full control of the wrapper component as well as the children components. Currently with the quick prototype I put together I can't edit the children only the wrapper component when I try to edit the group.

Comment: Ah ok. I've ran into the same problem once. Make sure all the tags are properly closed. For one case I needed to forcibly disable decoration for the include (ended up writing an own include tag where I did the following: componentContext.setDefaultDecorationTagName(""); )